# Hide / Show text box based on radio button in SharePoint 365

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-online

I am new at coding in SharePoint. I have created a form which has multiple radio buttons. I want to hide or show text box based on radio button selection.

1) Field Name: Is this an urgent request

2) Radio button Option: Yes/No

3) Field Name: Justification for urgency

If the user selects Yes, I want the field 3) to be shown else hidden. I have added the below code in script editor and is working perfect.

Now the question is, I have another field with same Yes/No option and how to expand the code for this:

4) Field Name: Is this critical client

5) Radio button Option: Yes/No

6) Field Name: Brief description of client

If the user selects Yes, I want the field 6) to be shown else hidden.
Code that is working perfect for 1) to 3)

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){  
    $("span[title='Yes']>input").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("nobr:contains('Justification for urgency')").closest('tr').show();

        }    
    });
    $("span[title='No']>input").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("nobr:contains('Justification for urgency')").closest('tr').hide();

        }else{
            $("nobr:contains('Justification for urgency')").closest('tr').hide();

        } 
    });
});
</script>
```

Also, is there a way if we make the hidden text box as mandatory, and while hiding, can it add a text as "NA" and hide.

Comment: It is difficult to give a real answer without test case. I'd suggest you to post your code on jsfiddle or codepen and give us a link to test, or create a snippet here.

Comment: Thank you Thanh Trung. I have no contorl over HTML. Used the default form. Javascrip for the first option which is working is here

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the HTML, I'd suggest you to create relationship between elements using attributes and class binding. Example:

```js
$('.yes_no_radio').change(function(){
  var targetClass = $(this).data('bind-to');
  var targets = $('.' + targetClass);
  //or $(this).closest('form').find('.' + targetClass)
  
  //convert to int then bool
  targets.toggle(!!+this.value);
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label>
    Yes 
    <input type="radio" class="yes_no_radio" data-bind-to="some_class" value="1" name="yes_no">
  </label>
  
  <label>
    No 
    <input type="radio" class="yes_no_radio" data-bind-to="some_class" value="0" name="yes_no">
  </label>
<div>

<div>
  FIELD A
</div>

<div class="some_class hide">
  FIELD B
</div>

<div>
  FIELD C
</div>

<div class="some_class hide">
  FIELD D
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery attribute selector to bind events to controls.

Sample script.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                var tr = $("nobr:contains('Is this an urgent request')").closest('tr');
                $('span[title="Yes"]>input', tr).change(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        $("nobr:contains('Justification for urgency')").closest('tr').show();

                    }
                })
                $('span[title="No"]>input', tr).change(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        $("nobr:contains('Justification for urgency')").closest('tr').hide();

                    }
                })
                var tr2 = $("nobr:contains('Is this critical client')").closest('tr');
                $('span[title="Yes"]>input', tr2).change(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        $("nobr:contains('Brief description of client')").closest('tr').show();

                    }
                })
                $('span[title="No"]>input', tr2).change(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        $("nobr:contains('Brief description of client')").closest('tr').hide();

                    }
                })
            });

    </script>
```

[image]

Update:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var tr = $("nobr:contains('Is this an urgent request')").closest('tr');
        $('span[title="Yes"]>input', tr).change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {                    
                $('input[title="Justification for urgency"]', $("nobr:contains('Justification for urgency')").closest('tr')).attr("disabled", false);
                $("nobr:contains('Justification for urgency')").closest('tr').show();

            }
        })
        $('span[title="No"]>input', tr).change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                //disable control
                $('input[title="Justification for urgency"]', $("nobr:contains('Justification for urgency')").closest('tr')).attr("disabled", true);
                //set text as NA
                $('input[title="Justification for urgency"]', $("nobr:contains('Justification for urgency')").closest('tr')).text("NA");
                $("nobr:contains('Justification for urgency')").closest('tr').hide();

            }
        })
        var tr2 = $("nobr:contains('Is this critical client')").closest('tr');
        $('span[title="Yes"]>input', tr2).change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('input[title="Brief description of client"]', $("nobr:contains('Brief description of client')").closest('tr')).attr("disabled", false);
                $("nobr:contains('Brief description of client')").closest('tr').show();

            }
        })
        $('span[title="No"]>input', tr2).change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('input[title="Brief description of client"]', $("nobr:contains('Brief description of client')").closest('tr')).attr("disabled", true);
                $("nobr:contains('Brief description of client')").closest('tr').hide();


            }
        })
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Its working perfect.Just wanted to check if I make the field "Justification for urgency" as mandatory, can we add text as NA before the field getting hidden

Comment: Thank you!!! NO the updated code is not adding text "NA" before hiding the filed "Justification for urgency"

Comment: Do you mean Justification for urgency NA[input area]?

Comment: Yes, I meant "NA" is not getting updated in "Justification for urgency" filed when the filed is getting hidden